# How to you write polars data frames to Azure blob storage?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, python-polars

Given a parquet file in Azure blob storage, this can be read into a polars dataframe using

```py
pl.read_parquet('az://{container-name}/{filename}', storage_options={'account_name': ..., 'account_key': ...})
```

(the above works via the optional dependency on `adlfs`)

Is there anything equivalent to `write_parquet`?

Comment: I think the [delta methods](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/io.html#delta-lake) are for this. The writer is currently being implemented: https://github.com/pola-rs/polars/pull/7616 - (there may also be a way to do it directly as of now - I've not used this part of polars)

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to make it work directly with Polars, but it works with PyArrow.

Here is what you can do:

```
import polars as pl
import pyarrow.parquet as pq
from adlfs import AzureBlobFileSystem

abfs = AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name='account_name',account_key='account_key')

pq.write_table(polars_dataframe.to_arrow(), 'container/file_name.parquet', filesystem=abfs)
```

Comment: see my answer for an alternative.

Comment: I like both, but for now `df.to_pandas().to_parquet(filepath, storage_options=...)` works

Comment: @MYK the pyarrow approach is going to be much more efficient than the pandas one as polars stores everything as arrow in memory so invoking `to_arrow()` is free whereas `to_pandas()` creates a copy.

Comment: @MYK. I understand. 
One improvement you could do (if it works) is to pass `.to_pandas(use_pyarrow_extension_array = True)`. This way the data stays in Arrow format, which should make the conversion to Pandas faster

Comment: I'll try the `to_arrow()` approach :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anything equivalent to write_parquet?

No.

What I do is monkey path in my own read and write methods onto the `pl` namespace to shortcut connection handling.

Assume you create a filesystem with `adlfs` or `fsspec` (the former is just a wrapper of the latter).

```
azfs=fsspec.filesystem('abfss', connection_string="lgkjsklgjklfherirtguyshasdfkj")
```

So maybe your boilerplate becomes:

```
import polars as pl
import fsspec
# The exact command to create the filesystem doesn't matter so long as it's a filesystem object.
azfs = fsspec.filesystem('abfss', connection_string="lgkjsklgjklfherirtguyshasdfkj")

def write_pq(self, REMOTE_PATH, **kwargs):
    with azfs.open(REMOTE_PATH, "wb") as file_pointer:
        self.write_parquet(file_pointer, **kwargs)
    
pl.DataFrame.write_pq=write_pq
```

For consistency you can also make a reader like this:

```
def read_pq(REMOTE_PATH, **kwargs):
    with azfs.open(REMOTE_PATH, "rb") as file_pointer:
        pl.read_parquet(file_pointer, **kwargs)
pl.read_pq=read_pq
```

Monkey patching the `read_pq` definition to `pl` doesn't really give you anything unless you're going to make a package of the above and load that instead of polars directly which is what I did so then if you call your package `mypolars` then in your future scripts, instead of `import polars as pl` you'd do `from mypolars import pl`.

Then from then on, you can just do `df.write_pq("your blob path")` and you can read it with `df=pl.read_pq("your blob path")`

Since we have `**kwargs` in the call, you can still use any other parameter available to the native `read_parquet` and `write_parquet`