# Writing in delta using Polars and adlfs

Tags: python, azure-storage, python-polars, fsspec

According to [How to you write polars data frames to Azure blob storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75800596),
we can write *parquet* using `polars` directly on *Azure Storage* such as basic storage containers.

In my case I was required to write in *Delta* format, which stands on top of *parquet*, so I modified the code a bit since `polars` [also supports delta](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.write_delta.html)

```py
import adlfs
import polars as pl
from azure.identity.aio import DefaultAzureCredential

# pdf: pl.DataFrame
# path: str
# account_name: str
# container_name: str

credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
fs = adlfs.AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name=account_name, credential=credential)

with fs.open(f"{container_name}/way/to/{path}", mode="wb") as f:
    if path.endswith(".parquet"):
        pdf.write_parquet(f)
    else:
        pdf.write_delta(f, mode="append")
```

Using this code, I was able to write on the Azure filesystem when I specified a `path = path/to/1.parquet` but not `path = path/to/delta_folder/`.

In the second case, my problem was only a 0 byte file was written to `delta_folder` on Azure storage, `f` being a file pointer.

What's more, If I just use the local filesystem using `pdf.write_delta(path, mode="append")` it just works.

How can I modify my code to support writing recursively in the `delta_folder/` in the cloud?

Comment: Is the 0 byte file a parquet file? What if you try with `mode=overwrite`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that delta wants a folder to write to (potentially) multiple files so `fsspec`'s model of opening one file at a time isn't going to work.

You'll need to do something like

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
credentials_dict = {} #objectstore syntax see link below
if path.endswith(".parquet"):
    with fs.open(f"{container_name}/way/to/{path}", mode="wb") as f:
        pdf.write_parquet(f)
else:
    pdf.write_delta(
         f"abfs://{container_name}/way/to/", 
         mode="append", 
         storage_options = credentials_dict
    )
```

See [here](https://docs.rs/object_store/latest/object_store/azure/enum.AzureConfigKey.html#variants) for the key fields that are compatible with `credentials_dict`

Comment: Thank you it works, I just have this strange mypy error `No overload variant of "write_delta" of "DataFrame" matches argument types "str", "str", "dict[str, str | None]"  [call-overload]`